# How to ask individual permissions for scopes while using google + sign in?

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-signin, onactivityresult

Right now am able to use google sign in with the following code. And I have added all the necessary scopes within it. But is it possible to ask `permission` for basic profile details in one `dialog` and accessing contacts from different `dialog`?

```
private void initGoogleLogin() {
        Scope SCOPE_CONTACTS_READ =
                new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly");
        gp.setOnClickListener(v -> signIn());
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
                .requestScopes(SCOPE_CONTACTS_READ)
                .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"))
                .requestIdToken(Constants.GOOGLESERVERAUTHCODE)
                .requestEmail().requestServerAuthCode(Constants.GOOGLESERVERAUTHCODE).requestProfile().build();
        mgoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        }
```

This code asks all the permissions in one dialog. But there is no option to deny sharing contacts. So how can i achieve the functionality where user can allow basic profile info and deny to share contacts. And how to handle it in `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the plus scopes you're requesting have been deprecated and will cause failures within a few days. See https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown

However, to request permissions on different screens, you should be able to [request additional scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/additional-scopes) when you need them, and gracefully handle if the user rejects them.

Untested, but something like:

```
GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
        MyActivity.this,
        RC_REQUEST_PERMISSION_CONTACTS,
        GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity()),
        SCOPE_CONTACTS_READ);
```

in `onActivityResults()` it might be something like

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (RC_REQUEST_PERMISSION_CONTACTS == requestCode) {
            // They've accepted it
        }
    }
}
```